# Failed spring boot app with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, netflix, openfeign

facing **NoSuchMethodError**, when I run my spring boot(v2.6.7) multi-module maven project, where I am interacting through **feign** client to other microservices.

**Main**

```
import org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.annotation.EnableProcessApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableProcessApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

***stacktrace***

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes.getAliasedString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.validate(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:209)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClient(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:178)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClients(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:167)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
```

Comment: could you share your pom ?

Comment: You need to update your Spring Cloud dependencies. The missing method – `AnnotationAttributes.getAliasedString` – was deprecated in Spring Framework 4.3.2 and removed in 5.0. Spring Boot 2.6.x uses Spring Framework 5.3.x so the method is long gone.